# How to deploy react.js webpack with django to heroku?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have a django backend and react.js frontend along with webpack. I've set everything up locally as per this page: http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/ and have my dev server running and all is peachy. For my production webpack file I've copied the same exact one as on the site.

However I would like to deploy to heroku and this is where I get stuck. Do I need to replace my webpack-dev-server with some kind of express server on production?

Can I just run django and serve up static javascript files instead? To generate these files I've tried running:  "webpack webpack-config.prod.js --progress -p"
however I get a bunch of "Cannot resolve module 'fs'" errors but I do notice it generated a 900kb js file in assets/bundles.

Also if I try running "webpack webpack-config.prod.js --progress -p" on my local machine (without the dev server) and go to a django route I get this in my console:

GET http://localhost:3000/assets/bundles/main-62ddfced1c44b3270fa7.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have spent quite a few hours getting this to work, setting up the dev environment was a lot faster. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You definitely should not be using webpack-dev-server in production - it actually says as much in the [readme](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed any of your dependencies with the `--save-dev` flag, like the guide you linked to suggests then they won't get installed on heroku since it runs `npm install` with the production flag set. So if `fs` is under `devDependencies` in your package.json it is not going to be installed.

As far as I know there's two options here. You can either put the generated bundle under version control so it gets pushed to heroku **or** you can install your dependencies with just the `--save` flag. I personally prefer using `--save` if I will be publishing on heroku and then add a package.json script called `heroku-postbuild` that runs webpack and builds the bundle.

```
"scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run dist",
},
```

Comment: 'fs' was not in the requirements for dev or production. In fact when I try to do "webpack webpack.config.js" (the non prod config) I also get the same 'fs' error.

Comment: Are you running that from the command-line? Because then the script that tries to require `fs` will be looking for it in the global scope. If you put it in an npm script it will actually look in the local node_modules/ folder.

Comment: What version of node are you using? If it came with npm v3 then any module you've installed will install its dependencies directly in node_modules (where v2 would nest them). If that's the case we're probably back to moving dependencies out of `devDependencies`.